# Inverse of a noisy derivative

Tags: python, mean, derivative

I have a series of samples `(x(t), y(t))`, where both are noisy and with (assumed) iid errors `(sx(t), sy(t))`.  I need to measure a function `z(x',y) = y(t) / x'(t)`.  However, because the true `x'(t)` is close to zero, the noise causes `x_meas` to jump up and down across 0, and therefore `z_meas` jumps up and down across 0 and up to infinity, because some values are extremely close to 0.

Averaging the final result `<z(t)>` is basically worthless because of the infinities.  So where is the statistically best (least biased, etc) place to apply smoothing?

Ideally, I know what `x(t)` is supposed to be as the dependent variable, although there are open-loop errors so I can't treat that with an absolute. But it might still be the best place to apply a smoothing function (I've been using an SG filter, because it has less of a temporal offset and handles the corners when `x(t)` turns around).

Is it better to filter `x` and then take the derivative there, or filter `x'`?  (Or are those effectively the same thing? And as a secondary question, if I wanted to preserve the errors for propagation, is there something I should do?  Handling error for a running average is tricky.

...

Side note: whatever I do, z(t) becomes pathological when going from `x' > 0` to `x' < 0`. In theory `z(x',y)` shouldn't change at that corner, but it totally does.

Edit: on the shapes of the curves.
`x(t)` is either going to be a relatively slowly varying sine wave or sawtooth. In theory, `x'(t) = +/- k` where `k` is a constant. `y` is going to be a rough rectangle, where it is `y =~ x'(t) * (c + f(x,t))`. where `c` is a second constant and `f(x,t)` is an even more slowly varying function that is going to be roughly linear in `x`.  The reason `y` is a distorted rectangle is that when `x'` jumps from + to -, the sign of `y` is going to flip.

Comment: You can accomplish the most by (a) making specific assumptions about the family of error distributions and (b) making specific assumptions about the shapes of the curves $x$ and $y.$  What can you tell us about these?

Comment: An approach I've used with some success is to use a median filter first, then fit, say, a third or fifth order polynomial to the filtered data, then take the derivative of that. You're definitely better off smoothing before differentiating, since differentiation inherently amplifies noise.

Comment: are you trying to fit and estimate $c+f(x,t)$? can you show some graphs or sample data?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very easy. First, fit a periodic function to $x(t)$. Once you got your $x(t)$, calculate $x'(t)$ analytically. Whether it's a saw tooth, sine or anything else isn't essential. The essential is to get the fit, then calculate analytical derivative. The rest is trivial: get your $\frac {y(t)}{x'(t)}$ and fit your function to it.

Comment: This looks the opposite of "very easy." (1) Why must the fit be periodic?  (2) Even if it should be, what should be the fitting criterion (loss function)?  (3) How can one go about determining a margin of error for the estimate of $z$?

Comment: OP’s x is periodic, so it must be for as periodic. It works very well, I’ve done similar stuff in signal analysis

Comment: It's vaguely periodic in the design function, but that's open loop, and several elements "upstream" as it were. So there are all sorts of drift effects to consider, plus it doesn't end up actually looking like a sawtooth. So I cannot just perform a fit to the function I was using.

Comment: @Necarion, show us how it looks, maybe. with derivatives your best chance is in parametric fits. in your case the noise will make it hard to get anything reasonable with nonparametric filtering\